# How to find a particular solution with given eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose A has eigenvalues 0, 3, 5 with independent eigenvectors u, v, w.
Find a particular solution to Ax= v + w. Find all solutions.

My intuition says that the answer is x = 1/3v + 1/5w since Av = 3v and Aw = 3w.
But how to solve it in proper way?

Comment: First, what is the dimension of your linear vector space? After that, what do you mean by *the proper way*? What you did is correct to find a particular solution $x_0$. Now if $x$ is a general solution, you have by linearity $A(x-x_0)=0$. And therefore $x-x_0$ belongs to the eigenspace associated with the zero eigenvalue, which is by the way the nullspace of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *almost* got it.

By the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, we have:

$$Au = 0$$
$$Av = 3v$$
$$Aw = 5w$$

A linear combination of the three vectors will have the form:

$$A(au + bv + cw) = 3bv + 5cw$$

Let $b = \frac{1}{3}$ and $c = \frac{1}{5}$ then:

$$A(au + \frac{1}{3}v + \frac{1}{5}w) = v + w$$

*But* note that the *a* is still there: It doesn't have any effect on the result of the matrix multiplication, it *can* be any arbitrary scalar (real or complex or whatever the domain of your vector elements is).  So

$$x = au + \frac{1}{3}v + \frac{1}{5}w$$

To find a *particular* solution, just plug in a concrete value for $a$: Zero will probably be easiest.

Comment: You provided **some solutions**, but you should also prove that there are no other solutions.

Comment: @Dan I'm a little confused about b and c, does it work with every vector? I mean A multiply any sx gives sb A(sx) = sb where s is scalar?

Comment: oh, I guess ive found it, A(rB)  =  r(AB) , is that it?

Comment: @Vanconts: Yes.  Unlike matrix×matrix multiplication, matrix×scalar is commutative.  So $Aav = aAv$.

Comment: @Dan Thank you <3